# Episode of "Outer Limits" or "Twilight Zone" where a robot takes blood from a little girl?

Tags: episode-identification, the-twilight-zone, the-outer-limits

When I was younger I watched all the old reruns on TV Land. There was a black and white episode about a robot/alien that was friends with a little girl. He was taking lots of blood from her every time she visited, in a spherical ball like glass container.

Eventually the father/mother finds out what is going on and kills the alien/robot/monster, but comes to find out he was taking blood to save the human race and just doomed everyone.

Comment: It *sounds* more like an Outer Limits kind of plot, but I say that with only familiarity of the newer run which was fond of the punch-twist ending, not the original B&W series.  I can at least say it doesn't sound like any Twilight Zone episode I know, or can find with a quick search.

Answer (score 5):

Minus the part about the alien taking blood, this sounds a bit like the *Twilight Zone* episode ["The Gift"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gift_(The_Twilight_Zone)) (1962). In it, it's a boy, not a girl that befriends an alien. People from the boy's village kill the alien, only to find out that he was on Earth to

> deliver a cure for cancer.